# Django - set expiry for a certain key in session

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session, django-sessions

I'm creating a Django application which allows visitors to vote on a list once every week. My app does not have a User model, so what I'm trying to do is set the session for a specific key to `True` to signify that the user has voted on that list. eg.

```
request.session['a'] = True
request.session.set_expiry(604800)
```

This works fine but the session expiry is set for the entire session and not just that key. How can I set expiry for a specific key in a Django session?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can recall, there is no way to expire specific keys. As a workaround, I'd suggest storing the date/time at which 'a' was set or updated.

With this data you can either create a middleware, which could be fairly heavy depending on the size of the session data, or alternatively create a cron job to run at regular intervals to expire all keys where the date/time they were set/updated is outside of your threshold.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to give **expiry time** to **specific session keys**.

So, if setting **the expiry time "60 seconds"** for **session** with **"set_expiry()"** as shown below, all session keys have **"60 seconds" expiry time**:

```py
request.session.set_expiry(60)
```

So, in this case, even for **Django Admin**, users can be logged in **only 60 seconds**. So after **60 seconds**, users are taken back to **the login page** as shown below:

[image]

In addition, as a test, I set **"120 and 60 seconds" expiry time** to  **two specific session keys "test1" and "test2"** respectively as shown below but for **both "test1" and "test2" session keys**, **"60 seconds"** is prioritized instead of **"120 seconds"**:

```py
# "views.py"

def test(request):

    request.session.set_expiry(120) # Not Prioritized
    request.session['test1'] = 'test1'
    
    request.session.set_expiry(60) # Prioritized
    request.session['test2'] = 'test2'

    return render(request, 'test/index.html')
```

This is **the session id** for **all session keys** as shown below:

[image]